# Supremum and Infimum of the function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I need help finding Supremum and Infimum

$f(x)=\frac{(x-1)}{x}\exp(\frac{-1}{|x|}) $ when $ x\not=0$ and $f(0)=0$

calculating derivative with $ \exp(\frac{-1}{|x|})$ is complicated. Is there a faster solution after the transformation?

Comment: After what transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have taht $f$ is smooth(!) and $f(x)\to 1$ as $|x|\to\infty$, hence the supremum and infimum are indeed either local extrema (and should be found using the derivative or possibly $0$ or $1$, respectively.
The desired values are the same as $\sup$ and $\inf$ of $g\colon\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb R$, $x\mapsto f(\frac1x)=(1-x)e^{-|x|}$.

For positive $x$, we have $g(x)=(1-x)e^{-x}$ and $g'(x)=-e^{-x}-(1-x)e^{-x}=(x-2)e^{-x}$ which is zero exactly when $x=2$.
Hence $g$ falls from $g(0)=1$ to $g(2)=-e^{-2}$ and then grows to $\lim_{x\to+\infty}g(x)=0$ an the positive axis.

For negative $x$, we have $g(x)=(1-x)e^{x}$ and $g'(x)=-e^{x}+(1-x)e^{x}=-xe^{-x}$ which is nonzero for negative $x$.
Hence $g$ falls from $g(0)=1$ to $\lim_{x\to+\infty}g(x)=0$ as $x$ walks along the negative axis.

We conclude that $\inf f=\inf g = -e^{-1}$ and $\sup f =\sup g = 1$.

Comment: what mean that f is smooth(!) and why when $f(x) \to 1 $as $|x|\to \infty$ the supremum and infimum are the same